# Using Context Manager, how can I implement the Indenter class in such a way that executing the following code results in as follows(output):

Tags: python, class, with-statement, contextmanager

```
with Identer() as indent:
     ident.print("Hi")
     with ident:
          ident.print("Talk is Cheap!")
          with ident:
               ident.print("Show me the Code...")
     ident.print("Torvalds")
```

OUTPUT:

```
Hi
   Talk is Cheap!
      Show me the Code... 
Torvalds
```

I don't know how to implement the context manager in such a way nested "with" statements are allowed. How can I receive the output by running the mentioned piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__enter__` and `__exit__` dunder methods to increase the indent prefix each time you enter a `with` statement, and decrease it when exiting the `with` statement.

For example:

```
from textwrap import indent

class Indenter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.level = -1

    def print(self, text):
        for _ in range(self.level):
             text = indent(text, "    ")
        print(text)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.level += 1
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.level -= 1




with Indenter() as ident:
     ident.print("Hi")
     with ident:
          ident.print("Talk is Cheap!")
          with ident:
               ident.print("Show me the Code...")
     ident.print("Torvalds")
```

Output:

```
Hi
    Talk is Cheap!
        Show me the Code...
Torvalds
```

It doesn't come out exactly as your expected output is but it should be enough to point you in the right direction with whatever it is you are trying to achieve.

If you wanted it to look exactly as your expected output you could rewrite your statement like this:

```
with Identer() as ident:
    ident.print("Hi")
    ident.print("Talk is Cheap!")
    with ident:
          ident.print("Show me the Code...")
    ident.print("Torvalds")
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Indenter:
    __indenter = "\t"

    def __init__(self):
        self._indent = -1

    def print(self, text):
        if self._indent > 0:
            print(f"{self.__indenter * self._indent}{text}")
        else:
            print(text)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._indent += 1
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self._indent -= 1


with Indenter() as ident:
    ident.print("Hi")
    with ident:
        ident.print("Talk is Cheap!")
        with ident:
            ident.print("Show me the Code...")
    ident.print("Torvalds")
```

output:

```
Hi
    Talk is Cheap!
        Show me the Code...
Torvalds
```